# Cstruct and Lwt_bytes

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt

As far as I can tell, Lwt_bytes seems to use the same type as Cstruct (or probably uses cstruct itself), but some some reason I can't make the two of them work together :

```
Lwt_io.write_from_exactly out b.Cstruct.buffer 0 16


Error: This expression has type
         Cstruct.buffer =
           (char, Bigarray.int8_unsigned_elt, Bigarray.c_layout)
           Bigarray.Array1.t
       but an expression was expected of type bytes
```

Isn't bytes that exact same type ? How can I make that work ? I'm trying to use Cstruct instead of Lwt_bytes for the convenience of Cstruct.LE, which bytes doesn't seem to have.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, the second argument of [Lwt_io.write_from_exactly](https://ocsigen.org/lwt/3.2.1/api/Lwt_io#VALwrite_from_exactly) is of type `bytes` (a mutable OCaml string), whereas a [Cstruct.buffer](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cstruct/blob/3cc3e6774d9c702204367e140b7c5d79bb033f53/lib/cstruct.mli#L139) is a Bigarray of 8-bit integers.
While the underlying "payloads" are the same (word-aligned arrays of unsigned chars; see the [Bytes_val](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/d3e73595e55e84250fa77f04e9c239dee1224b7b/runtime/caml/mlvalues.h#L260) macro), the "value wrappers" at the OCaml level are different (see, for example, [caml_ba_alloc](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/d3e73595e55e84250fa77f04e9c239dee1224b7b/runtime/bigarray.c#L92)).

Have you tried using [Lwt_bytes.to_bytes](https://ocsigen.org/lwt/3.2.1/api/Lwt_bytes#VALto_bytes) to convert from one to the other?

Unfortunately, this [seems to duplicate and copy the data payload](https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/blob/fe5f3cd0db771d14a13b896c1e1047bb06952c65/src/unix/lwt_bytes.ml#L73), so it may be better to rethink your overall approach. There's not enough information in your question to make a more precise suggestion.

Comment: This answer is correct. To elaborate a bit, `Lwt_bytes.t`s *are* bigarrays compatible with Cstruct, but `bytes` is a core OCaml type, the type of mutable strings. The naming is confusing, so it's easy to think that `bytes` = `Lwt_bytes.t`. The reason for this is that `Lwt_bytes` was given its name long before `bytes` was added as a new type to the core language. `Lwt_io` is built over `bytes`, i.e. regular (mutable) OCaml strings. To do I/O with `Lwt_bytes.t`, it's necessary to use the functions in module `Lwt_bytes` (or other bigarray libraries).

Comment: I also want to note that asynchronous I/O with `string`s or `bytes` (like in `Lwt_io`) is almost always less efficient that I/O with bigstrings (like Cstruct, `Lwt_bytes`). This is because `string` and `bytes` storage is managed by the garbage collector, and can be moved, so Lwt (or any other I/O lib) has to do an internal copy, so the address of the data remains fixed for the duration of the I/O. Bigstrings (`Lwt_bytes.t`, Cstruct) are inherently allocated with fixed storage, so I/O requires no copying. The `Lwt_bytes` API is not (currently) as rich as `Lwt_io`, however.

Comment: I understand, I had indeed not realized Lwt_bytes.t and bytes weren't the same. It makes a lot more sense now, and using bytes does work fine. Since I am using Lwt_io, I just replaced cstruct with bytes